# Can't load any serial libraries that call native code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to connect over serial on an Android tablet with built in serial ports which works with some basic c code but I can't load any third party libraries that have native code.

The [jlibmodbus](https://github.com/kochedykov/jlibmodbus) works with several serial libraries but I have issues when calling

```
        System.loadLibrary("jssc");
```

or `RxTx` `jSerialComm`

All complain about `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` in some way or another even when I have added NDK locations and `.so.` files.

Comment: Can you share folder structure for jniLibs?

Comment: Folders  armeabi-v7a  and armeabi contain the so files